# De Python-Tkinter a webb

Tags: python, web, tkinter, app

Estoy aprendiendo a programar aplicaciones en Python usando Tkinter. La verdad es que ya la tengo programada, pero me gustaría crear una web para poder usarla desde cualquier ordenador/movil ¿Podría aprovechar el código?

Muchas gracias!

Comment: Como la respuesta de @cls simplemente no se puede ya que tkinter es C y C no se puede usar en la web a no ser que uses WebAssembly pero necesitarías un compilador de C a WebAssembly y experiencia en C, te recomiendo django o de plano haz la pagina en HTML, CSS y JS

Comment: Bienvenida Mario, nos alegra que te sumes a stackoverflow. Para que tus preguntas sean mejor recibidas te sugiero revisar esta pagina donde muestran [como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/asking). También puedes realizar el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que aprendas un poco más de como funciona la pagina y de paso ganar tur primeras medallas.

Answer (score 1):

Simplemente no puedes, Tkinter te sirve para hacer una aplicación para tu ordenador, si quieres hacerlo web, tendrías que reescribir todo el código utilizando otra librería de Python.